# Template aliases and dependent names

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer

While thinking how *CRTP* can be improved in **C++11**, I ended with the following code:

```
template <typename Derived, typename Delayer>
struct derived_value_type
{
  typedef typename Derived::value_type type;
};

template <typename Derived>
struct base
{
  template <typename Delayer = void>
  typename derived_value_type<Derived, Delayer>::type
  foo(){ return {}; }
};

struct derived : base<derived>
{
  typedef int value_type;
};

#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
  derived d;
  auto bar = d.foo();

  std::cout << typeid(bar).name() << ':' << bar << std::endl;
}
```

I believe the previous code to be standard conformant, and it compiles and works with the major compilers (resulting in `i:0`). However, when I use a template alias instead, I get a compilation error due to `derived` being incomplete:

```
template <typename Derived, typename Delayer>
using derived_value_type = typename Derived::value_type;

/*...*/

template <typename Delayer = void>
derived_value_type<Derived, Delayer>
foo(){ return {}; }
```

Is this a compiler bug, or does the fact that the compiler can determinate that there is no real dependency with `Delayer` mean that the template alias is not a dependent type? Where is this specified in the standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class templates and function templates are instantiated, but alias templates are simply substituted.  And by getting rid of the member name `type`, you lose a chance at invoking the dependent name lookup rules.

[N3285] 14.5.7p2:

> When a *template-id* refers to the specialization of an alias template, it is equivalent to the associated type obtained by substitution of its *template-arguments* for the *template-parameters* in the *type-id* of the alias template.

So in the first case, you have:

The definition of `struct derived` requires the implicit instantiation of `base<derived>`.  During this instantiation, we discover `base<derived>` has a member function template:

```
template <typename Delayer=void>
typename derived_value_type<derived, Delayer>::type foo();
```

The return type is dependent, so `type` is not yet looked up, and no specialization of `derived_value_type` is instantiated.  The instantiation finishes, and `base<derived>` and `derived` are both now complete types.

In `main`, the expression `d.foo()` requires the implicit instantiation of `base<derived>::foo<void>()`.  Now the name `typename derived_value_type<derived, void>::type` is looked up, instantiating `derived_value_type<derived, void>` along the way.  The return type is found to be `int`.

In the second case, `derived_value_type` is not a dependent name, so is bound to your alias template declaration at the definition of template `base<D>`.  The compiler could do the alias substitution either at the template definition or during each instantiation of the class, but either way you get a class template equivalent to:

```
template <typename Derived>
struct base
{
  template <typename Delayer = void>
  typename Derived::value_type
  foo(){ return {}; }
};
```

The definition of `struct derived` requires the implicit instantiation of `base<derived>`.  During this instantiation, we discover `base<derived>` has a member function template:

```
template <typename Delayer=void>
typename derived::value_type foo();
```

But `derived::value_type` is not dependent, and `derived` is an incomplete type, so the code is ill-formed.